# Adding text-shadow (textShadow) .css() not working Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a shadow to the text in a div, with Jquery.

I found it can be done by using  camelCase and removing the hyphen....this works when no opacity is added to the shadow...

How can I make this work?

```
 .css("'textShadow",'0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 20, 0, 0.7);');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax problems with your code, which is why it isn't working.

Firstly, you don't need the enclosing semicolon within the function; jQuery's `.css` function will automatically handle that for you. Including it will just detect the CSS to be an invalid syntax.

In addition, you also have a stray hyphen in your code. It should read as `"textShadow"`, rather than `"'textShadow"`.

With these changes made, your code would look something like this:

```
.css("textShadow", '0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 20, 0, 0.7)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.css('textShadow','0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 20, 0, 0.7)');
```

Comment: Adding some description helps to understand what is fixed here, and what the problem was.